# Python 3.5: Subprocess sudo shutdown -h returns empty response, other command works fine

Tags: python-3.5

I am using following code to run linux command with python3.5

```
process = subprocess.run(['sudo shutdown -h'], check=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = process.stdout.decode('utf-8')

print("Response")
print(output)
```

It returns empty string as response

```
Shutdown scheduled for Tue 2019-09-10 22:32:34 CEST, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
Response
```

But when I replace command wit something with

```
ls -l
```

or

```
sudo su
```

it works, it returs string containing e.g. list of files in directory, like it should work

**Edit**
Apparently
Commands may send whatever they want to stdout or stderr, and this is completed unrelated to the status the command returns. While stderr is meant for diagnostic messages`, it is up to the program to decide where is sends messages
So one of solutions is to redirect stderr to stdout adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`

```
subprocess.run(['sudo shutdown -h'], check=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Comment: You are only catching `stdout`.  The shutdown message you showed is probably going to `stderr`.

Comment: You are right, but could you explain me why is that happening, output was in stderr

Comment: Commands may send whatever they want to `stdout` or `stderr`, and this is completed unrelated to the status the command returns.  While `stderr` is meant for diagnostic messages`, it is up to the program to decide where is sends messages.

Comment: ok, so I could just add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to redirect stderr to stdout

Comment: Yes, I believe that should work fine for this case.

Comment: Ok, mate tnx for your help